# How to linearize these terms in many different variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, nonlinear

How to linearize these terms in `q[t]` and `p[t,y]`

```
term1=(covd[Derivative[1][q][t] + Derivative[1, 0][p][t, y], t] + 
      2*(1 + 2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])*(Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]*  (4*(p[t, y] + q[t])*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y] - 
                a[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][p][t, y]) + 
      2*a[t, y]*(p[t, y] + q[t])* Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y]))/(2*a[t, y]^2*(p[t, y] + q[t])^3* (1 + 2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]))


term2=(Derivative[0, 1][a][t,y]*(4*(p[t, y] + q[t])*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y] - a[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][p][t, y]) + 2*a[t, y]*(p[t, y] + q[t])*
        Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y])/(a[t, y]^2*(p[t, y] + q[t])^3)
```

the codes I use are:

`Normal[Series[term1 /. {q -> (eps q[#] &), p -> (eps p[#] &)}, {eps, 0, 1}]]`

The output is:

```
(2*(1 + 2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])*(4*(p[t] + q[t])* Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]^2 + 
             2*a[t, y]*(p[t] + q[t])*Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y]) +     (Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1][q][t])* Derivative[1, 0][covd][0, t])/
     (2*eps^2*a[t, y]^2*(p[t] + q[t])^3*(1 + 
      2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])) + 
   ((Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1][q][t])^2*
    Derivative[2, 0][covd][0, t])/
     (4*eps*a[t, y]^2*(p[t] + q[t])^3*(1 + 
      2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])) + 
   ((Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1][q][t])^3*
    Derivative[3, 0][covd][0, t])/
     (12*a[t, y]^2*(p[t] + q[t])^3*(1 + 
      2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])) + 
   (eps*(Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1][q][t])^4*    Derivative[4, 0][covd][0, t])/(48*a[t, y]^2*(p[t] + q[t])^3*
        (1 + 2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]))
```

So it did not linearized cause `(q[t]+p[t,y])^3` still there

or:

`Normal[Series[term2 /. {q -> Function[{t}, eps q[t]], p -> Function[{t, y}, eps p[t, y]]}, {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1`

The output returns the same function.

Comment: Use the replacement `term1 /. {q :> (eps q[##] &), p :> (eps p[##] &)}`. Otherwise `p[t, y]` will be replaced by `eps p[t]`.

Comment: At which point do you want to linearize this? Currently, you seem to trying that at $q = 0$ and $p = 0$ where the expression has a pole of order 3 (so the expression is not linearizable there).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. The replacements works, thanks. `q[t]` and `p[t]` do not equal zero so the terms linearized and only `(q[t]+p[t])^2` remains.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
DerivativeWithRespectToq = D[
   term1 /. {q[args__] :> (q[args] + eps u[args])},
   eps
   ] /. {eps -> 0, u[args___] :> 1}

DerivativeWithRespectTop = D[
   term1 /.  {p[args__] :> (p[args] + eps v[args])},
   eps
   ] /. {eps -> 0, v[args___] :> 1}
```